# Why aren't C++ types const by default?

Tags: c++

Gurus everywhere tell us to `const` everything unless we need to modify it, yet the standard makes everything mutable until we *declare* it  `const`.

Am I missing something here, or is this a contradiction? Why aren't C++ types `const` by default when, according to the experts (some of whom presumably designed the standard), they should be *made* `const` by default?

Comment: I'd say this comes from at least historical reasons in compliance with compatibility to the [tag:c] language.

Comment: Meanwhile, in another language: "*Why is everything const by default when I need so much mutable state?*"

Comment: It comes from good old times, when programming was done just to make things working.

Comment: @syam What's your point? Language design is full of trade offs, but apparently the gurus agree that `const`-by-default is good for C++ (interacts well with the rest of the language, fits the applications it's used for, etc.).

Comment: You can read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157523/why-would-you-use-the-keyword-const-if-you-already-know-variable-should-be-const)

Comment: @delnan My point is that you need much more mutable objects than const ones. And IMHO, const-by-default wouldn't play that well with the rest of the language (eg. concerning move semantics, const-by-default would mean inefficient-by-default). I do agree that constness is good and is an integral part of a well designed program, but I disagree on the fact that it should be the default, it would be too impractical.

Comment: @delnan IMO the only place where const-by-default would perhaps be useful is for function parameters. But no more. And I'm not even sure of that.

Comment: Is the question talking about self-proclaimed gurus?

Comment: Well, C++ is not the language you are looking for.  The gurus that advocate const everywhere also ought to be suggesting more suitable languages.  Trying to adapt C++ to a const everywhere paradigm will end in tears.  Now "const correctness" on the other hand is a worthwhile endeavor for C++; but I've seen large projects that are pretty much const-free, and they still work just fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Gurus everywhere tell us to const everything unless we need to modify it,

That's been conventional wisdom for a decade or two, yes.

> yet the standard makes everything mutable until we declare it const.

The standard has evolved from languages developed around fifty years ago, when const-correctness, and even type checking, were largely regarded as being only of academic interest.

> Am I missing something here, or is this a contradiction?

It's not a contradiction; just a language that doesn't work how some would say it should. You still can (and should) declare things `const` where appropriate, and we just have to put up with a language that doesn't push us towards safe practices.

> Why aren't C++ types `const` by default?

Because changing such a fundamental aspect of the language will break just about all existing code. That's a much bigger concern than slightly reducing the scope for mistakes.

Comment: Are you suggesting things like `const int foo(const int)`?

Comment: @6502: `const` on return type doesn't make sense, but in the parameter, it does. I'm talking about your specific example.

Answer (score 17):

> Gurus everywhere tell us to const everything **unless** we need to modify it,

This makes sense to **me**. Immutability is a very noble idea.

<sup>[Rust](http://rust-lang.org/) is a new language (developed by Mozilla) in which variables, by default, are *immutable*. If you want your variables to be mutable, then you've to make it *mutable* explicitly by using the keyword `mut` which is exactly opposite of what C++ does — in C++, you've to make things *immutable* explicitly by using the keyword `const`, otherwise they're *mutable* by default.</sup>

Especially with the advent of multicore  processors and *more* multi-threading software than ever before, it makes *more* sense to me. I think by default there should be more restriction and the restriction should be lifted (when you need to) consciously and explicitly (as opposed to implicitly). For example, members of a class are `private` by default; the inheritance is `private` by default. You make them `public` or `protected` explicitly. So should be the case with *the-right-to-modify* a variable. You should not have right to modify a variable, by default (in my opinion). It requires a bit of maturity to appreciate immutability/restriction — by putting restriction, you avoid a whole class of bugs in your software. That is my thought, in support of the statement.

Now coming back to the actual question,

> Why aren't C++ types const by default when, according to the const-people they should be made const by default?

It is because

- Not many programmers realized that immutability (as the default) makes their life easy, as it is a sort of new trend, at least it is catching up very recently.
- backward-compatibility. C has mutable types by default.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @delnan: Does it now?

Comment: I don't see any reason to include the first half, but yes, the second part is an answer (whether it's a good one is a different matter, I'm not sure yet).

Comment: @delnan: The first is in support of the statement (because I've not seen many people talking about immutability as default), because I've to first agree with the statement first. The second part depends on how I think of the first part.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question a few years ago, and I wrote some helper functions to make the use of const variable more terse.

You can see it here : 
https://github.com/pthom/cpp_terse_const

And my post on codereview at stackechange :
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106074/const-by-default

Beware, this was just an exercice, I do not use this in production.