# Why use const proactively? C++

Tags: c++, constants

I read a lot article from website, it said that const help to understand the source better because you have an insurance that the value is fixed. Is this the only reason using const?

Comment: Read the duplicate topic. [My answer addresses your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19478103/415784).

Comment: And never underestimate the power of giving the optimizer as much up-front ammunition as you can for a well-done job. It isn't just good practice, its *beneficial* in multiple way. The above link is pretty solid, btw.

Comment: Oh okay.. :D 
Can I ask what does it mean by const is viral? means if one uses it once it must be used everywhere? but why? 
Sorry for my ignorance, I am new to c++.

Answer (score 0):

By using `const` you are using the compiler to spot when you are trying to write to something that you shouldn't.  I think that having the compiler tell me that I am doing something wrong is always good.  Also many compilers will optimise more efficiently when given the information that something in not ever going to change.

Answer (score -1):

It's a good reason, but another is that when you use references wheither they are const or not makes a big difference. For instance

```
void f(string& ref);
void g(const string& ref);
string h();

f(h()); // illegal code
g(h()); // legal code
```

The difference is because of the rule you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference. The return value of `h` is a temporary, and so only the call to `g` is legal. If you have `f` you would need to use an additional variable

```
string tmp = h();
f(tmp);
```

Comment: I don't think it answers the question, What if one writes `void f(string && ref);`? Do you know `f(h());` would be legal then?

Comment: @Nawaz No I didn't, still seems like a reasonable answer though.

Comment: It is not reasonable. If `g()` needs to store `ref` in an internal storage, then a copy would be created which is unnecessary if you pass `&&` which can be *moved*. Again, you've third (better) option, pass by value, then move the object to the internal storage.

Comment: Sorry but the purpose of the answer was not to illustrate best coding practice.

Comment: So what does your answer illustrate? That "how NOT to code"?

Comment: Can I ask what does it mean by const is viral? means if one uses it once it must be used everywhere? but why? Sorry for my ignorance, I am new to c++.

Comment: @Nawaz Now I'm in a bad mood, why don't you just go away, you're not contributing anything.

Comment: -1 for "contributing" a BAD answer. I mean, seriously, this is a very bad answer. If you edit and improve it, then I will remove the downvote, though.

Comment: @Nawaz Tell you what, I was about the answer Thunders question about why const is viral, but why don't you take the oppotunity to answer a question. Maybe it will help the OP.

Comment: @john: I've already done that in the other topic. See the link to the duplicate.

Comment: @john: Why? Because I've answered the question?

Comment: Chill Chill.. :)

@Nawaz [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478034/why-arent-c-types-const-by-default/19478103#19478103)

Comment: Nawaz Thanks.. :D

@john Can I have your answer for my question too? :)

Comment: @john John? Can I have your answer for my question too? :)